# : [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 773, v1db1 ]

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I am getting the following error in the logs. Though we are supplying the correct user name and password to login to the website. The LDAP is giving this error.

> : [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 773, v1db1 ]

Any suggestions would be really appreciable.

The login was working fine previously. We are suddenly facing this issue. And getting the above mentioned error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

data 773 means you need to reset the password

Please check this article for further knowledge :
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21290631

Answer (score 2):

This link is helpful :)

http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/Common%20Active%20Directory%20Bind%20Errors

Your problem is due to:

'Password Expiration: Entry's password must be changed before logging on LDAP pwdLastSet: value of 0 indicates admin-required password change - MUST_CHANGE_PASSWD'

Answer (score -1):

The websites mentioned above are all no longer valid. You can currently refer to the following.  [ldapwiki.com](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Wiki.jsp?page=Common%20Active%20Directory%20Bind%20Errors)